# Too many get_template_parts?

Tags: get-template-part

For a lot of my site I'm using `get_template_part` mostly because I had coded most of it in html/css first and it just seemed easier to call each part as I saw fit.

My question is, basically, will this have a noticeable impact on performance? If I'm calling in say 3 or 4 template parts. How many would you say is too many, if I was only bringing in little snippets.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my opinion three or four calls of `get_template_part()` is perfectly acceptable and even within the norm for some of the larger and more complex themes out there.

I don't know how many is too many but I think it would have to be a pretty large number to notice a hit in performance.

### A Deeper Look

[`get_template_part()`](http://wpseek.com/get_template_part/) calls `locate_template()`.

[`locate_template()`](http://wpseek.com/locate_template/) uses a `foreach()` loop to run `file_exists()` against your theme directory.

#### Performance of file_exists()

According to [this post about the performance of `file_exists()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316629/is-file-exist-in-php-a-very-expensive-operation), PHP automatically caches the results of the function to improve performance. Overall it is considered to be rather fast.

#### Performance of foreach()

[This post about the performance of `foreach()` vs `for()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php) concludes that generally there is little discernible difference between the two. However, it doesn't directly address the performance of `foreach()` on its own. For that, this post on [how `foreach()` really works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works/14854568#14854568) dives deep into the function. It states the following.

1.`foreach()` *can* be slow because it has to copy the array but in most cases usually isn't.

2.`foreach()` is usually transparent in its behavior.

3.`foreach()` can behave strangely if the array is modified within the loop.

### In summary

It would appear that a call to `get_template_part()` should be relatively quick. A loop within `locate_template()` must be used and `foreach()` appears to be as good a tool for the job as any other. `file_exists()` will then cache its results. The only direct control we have over the performance of `get_template_part()` is the number of files within the template directory.

Unless you have hundreds of template files to look through or are making an equally silly number of calls to `get_template_part()` the change in your site's performance should be negligible.

Comment: Great investigative and detailed Answer, kudos for that.

Comment: Excellent explanation. See also this trac  ticket for more detail https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/40731

Answer (score 2):

3 or 4 `get_template_parts` calls are not going to make any noticeable impact on performance whatsoever. You'd probably have to get into the hundreds before perceiving any issue (if then).